# run shell script in program and input parameters

Tags: shell

I am writing a C++ program for MAC OSX and I have a third parity program "parse" which is for uploading some .js to their server. There are just few cmd line to run in Terminal.

```
>parse new [folder]
Login>[email]
Pw>[pw]
projectID>[pid]
```

I want to auto. this process in my program, but I don't know how to pack all cmd togather.

when I call `system("parse new [folder] && [email] && [pw] && [pid]");`

the process hold at Login>

then I call `system("parse new [folder] && wait && [email] && wait && [pw] && wait && [pid]");`

it still hold at Login>

I would like to ask how can I input parameters for the cmd? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't remember exactly what the command was called, but it exists!

Now, I have found it. The `expect` command will wait for a prompt like the one you have described, and then it will pretend to be a keyboard and it will enter data. A quick example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect


set timeout 20

spawn "./parse"

FOLDER="/x/y/z"
LOGIN="Randy"
PASSWORD="horse_stapler"
PROJECTID="136729"


expect "parse new " { send "$FOLDER" }
expect "Login>" { send "$LOGIN" }
expect "Pw>" { send "$PASSWORD" }
expect "projectID>" { send "$PROJECTID" }

interact
```

... more examples like this one [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/).

**BUT WAIT.**

There are 2 things that you *need* to know.

Firstly, The reason that the top of the script is "#!/usr/bin/expect" is because this is not bash. Instead this is it's own special kind of script. Read more at the link.

**THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT.** I'm not going to get into this, but NEVER, EVER store a password as plain text within a program. Do not give this program to people with their plain text password because it is a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: `expect` is a good solution, and if `pw` is 'password' (which seems very plausible), then this advice is correct — don't store passwords in programs.

Comment: thank you both. I still working on, and you give me a big hints

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The `parse` program appears to be reading from standard input.  If that's correct, you'll need to ensure that it is given the email, directory and project ID on separate lines of input.

Test whether this works from a simple shell script:

```
parse new [folder] <<EOF
[email]
[pw]
[pid]
EOF
```

If it works, then you need to format the same command with multiple lines in the string you pass to `system()`.

If it doesn't work, it suggests that the `parse` program is reading from something other than standard input; it might be futzing with `/dev/tty` or something else.  I'd look hard at what it does with `strace` or a similar program to see what system calls it actually makes.

Your code using `&&` etc won't work; that runs the `parse` command, and if it is successful, runs a program `[email]`, and if by some mischance that works, then it runs `[pw]`, and `[pid]`.